# mysql_query does not return a resource

Tags: php, mysql

I've been all up and down StackExchange, and much of the internet's cornucopia of lesser sites, looking for any good reason my code doesn't work, but this one has me stumped. I'd like to display the total number of rows in a particular MySQL table, and set the count as a variable, to use later in the script. When I run the following, the script dies, and I get a PHP warning, telling me that mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given.

```
$conn = mysql_connect('mysql_server', 'username', 'password');
if (!$conn) {
    die('Connect Error ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('my_database', $conn);
if (!mysql_select_db('my_database')) {
    die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());
}
$max_count_query = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table");
// Perform Query
$max_count_action = mysql_query($max_count_query);
$mcount = mysql_result($max_count_action, 0, 0);
printf("\nNumber of Records to Process: ", $mcount);
```

What does the collective genius of StackOverflow think?

In response to the comments, I have another mini-slab of code to offer:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password');
if (!$conn) {
    die('Connect Error ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('my_database', $conn);
if (!mysql_select_db('my_database')) {
    die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());
}
$max_count_query = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM directory_nap");
// Perform Query
$max_count_action = mysql_query($max_count_query);
if (!$max_count_action){
    die('mysql query error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
$mcount = mysql_result($max_count_action, 0, 0);
if (!$mcount){
    die('mysql result error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
printf("\nNumber of Records to Process: ", $mcount);
```

Comment: Are you sure the parenthesis are not screwing it up?

Comment: you check the connection worked, you check the selecting of the db worked, but you don't check the query did.

Comment: Try: SELECT COUNT(all) from...

Comment: @denonth `SELECT COUNT(all)....` is not a valid mysql query, unless he happens to have a column named `all`

Comment: Why did you omit `mysql_error()` from the line that was giving you trouble but have it on every other line?

Comment: What is the output of second code snippet?

Comment: Indeed... does it make it past the `if (!$max_count_action)` line? It should, since your error is reporting `$max_count_action` as a string (which it should not be). If it isn't making it past the ! check, what is the `mysql_error`, if it IS making it past that check, `var_dump($max_count_action)` and let's see what in the crap it is!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided the `table` tablename is just a sample (see answer by bitfox), there's nothing wrong with your code. I can use the same code on my test server and get results by changing the table name to one that I know exists in my own db.

What is most troubling, however, is that you indicate the error says `mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given` -- if your SQL has an error, `mysql_query` returns boolean ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)), not a string. So, you're either not showing the same test code as you're actually using, or you've given us an inaccurate error message.

At some point, you **must** be assigning a string into the variable `$max_count_action`. Here's what I get when I send a query with an intentional problem: `Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given` -- note "boolean", not string.

So, I think your first step is to choose a different table name. That said, if you're using a reserved word as a table or column name you can still access it by surrounding the string in the backtick (`) character:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`
```

Second step is to see what's happening to `$max_count_action` to turn it into a string. Finally, use `mysql_error` consistently to debug, I would suggest doing something a little nicer with it than `die` for production code, however.

```
// working code on my test server
$max_count_query = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users");
$max_count_action = mysql_query($max_count_query);
$mcount = $max_count_action ? mysql_result($max_count_action, 0) : 'Error: '.mysql_error();
print "\nNumber of Records to Process: ". $mcount;
```

Comment: I was deeply perplexed by such an error, myself. After changing the code to what you see above, I now get `mysql_result() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given` ...I did my best to match the format of the official documentation, and my research seems to confirm what I have, yet the errors persist.

Comment: I was missing the required second parameter on `mysql_result`, try it now.

Comment: My running code is very similar to what you posted, thanks a million for that! It's much better looking now, too. ;)

Answer (score 1):

it's very likely that the error is here:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
```

"**table**" is a reserved word of SQL language. You should change it.

Comment: i'm guessing he was giving that as an example, a lot of people don't post there real values in the mistaken belief that it could be a security risk.

Comment: Dagon has it. The table is actually called `directory_nap`. Good catch, though. Thanks for the quick replies!

Comment: A question: did you try to execute the query from your mysql client? Did it return any results?

Comment: Another winning question, from bitfox. It works perfectly from the mysql client, telling me I have 3971 rows.

Comment: So as I pointed out, you're doing something with your variables that you don't show in the sample code. No matter **what**, `mysql_query` does not return a string, so your error indicates some other thing at play. Is `$max_count_action` global and being modified in an error handler!?

Comment: Other than the default globals, this function handles only local-scope variables. `$max_count_action` appears only in this part of the code, although the fruit of its labor is implemented in a counter, some 20 lines after this snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem is not clear from the code sample (it could be a wrong table name, the parentheses around the query string, and so on), however there are a number of inaccuracies in it. You can try the following code, it should at least fix a couple side bugs and give you more details on the error:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('mysql_server', 'username', 'password');
if ($conn === false) {
    die('Connect Error ' . mysql_error($conn));
}
if (mysql_select_db('my_database', $conn) === false) {
    die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error($conn));
}
$max_count_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table";
// Perform Query
$max_count_action = mysql_query($max_count_query, $conn);
if($max_count_action === false) {
    die('Query error ' . mysql_error($conn));
}
$mcount = mysql_result($max_count_action, 0, 0);
if($mcount === false) {
    die('Result retrieval error ' . mysql_error($conn));
}
printf("\nNumber of Records to Process: %s", $mcount);
mysql_free_result($max_count_action);
```

Hope this helps, bye!

Answer (score 0):

Is the 'table' in your question a placeholder or a real name in your code? Try to change another name of your 'table' table, otherwise I would like to try `mysql_fetch_array` instead of `mysql_result`

```
$max_count_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t";
// Perform Query
$max_count_action = mysql_query($max_count_query) or die (mysql_error());
$mcount = mysql_fetch_array($max_count_action);
printf("\nNumber of Records to Process: ", $mcount[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn = mysql_connect('mysql_server', 'username', 'password');
if (!$conn) {
    die('Connect Error ' . mysql_error());
}
```

This is OK, but the connect and coditional don't need to be split across 2 lines

```
mysql_select_db('my_database', $conn);
```

Again, this is questionable. If you're using multiple databases then referencing databases in your SQL is much simpler and safer than tracking state within your PHP code.

```
if (!mysql_select_db('my_database')) {
   die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Haven't you already done that?

```
$max_count_query = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table");
```

Why the brackets?

```
// Perform Query
```

Isn't that obvious from the code?

```
$max_count_action = mysql_query($max_count_query);
$mcount = mysql_result($max_count_action, 0, 0);
```

It would be neater to pass the db handle to the mysql_query call.

You checked for an error after connecting, you checked for an error after switching database, but you don't check for an error after mysql_query() ?

```
printf("\nNumber of Records to Process: ", $mcount);
```

There is no placeholder in the format string for the mcount argument.Try:

```
printf("\nNumber of Records to Process: %d", $mcount);
```

> I get a PHP warning, telling me that mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given.

Then the code you are running is not the code you've shown us; mysql_query() will not return a string.

Comment: At my skill level, a code review is welcome, too! I renamed `$max_count_action` to `$res`, and added symcbean's placeholder, and that appears to fix the problem. I'm not sure why naming the resource that way would affect its usability that way. I'd given it that name, as I couldn't unset `$result` ...There are a few other queries further down the code, and the data returned from all of them is needed simultaneously. Many thanks to all, for your generous contributions!